# How to transfer my chrome account data to another account?

Tags: google-chrome

I use chrome in macOS, and I want to transfer my chrome account data to another, I try to sign out, and sign in with another, but when I sign out, all datas will be cleared with following tips:

Because this account is managed by mydomains.com, your bookmarks, history, passwords, and other settings will be cleared from this device. However, your data will remain stored in your Google Account and can be managed on Google Dashboard.

So how can I transfer data to another account seamless?

Answer (score 2):

- Go to [this support article](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139)
- Expand tab "Change the Google Account where you save info"
- Follow the instructions